# If statement not behaving itself

Tags: reference

I have a very simple if statement that is looking to see if $_FILES[] is set and if so create a variable.  Here it is:

```
 if(isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])){$image="yes";}
```

So if it finds the files is in fact set, give $image the value of yes.  At the  moment, regardless of if its set or not, the value is being passed to $image.  Its driving me nuts.  Doesnt matter if I drop the ['name'] part even.  Ive been doing every incarnation of the if statement I can think of to make it behave but Im at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that checking to see if $_files isset will return a value in that even with no file being uploaded the array will contain information.  If you were to do var_dump on $files['photos']['name'] you will see that the value for that bit of information is 0 and therefore when checking to see if its set you will get a positive response.  This is how I overcame my problem:

```
    $foo =$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $foopoo =  $foo[0];
   if (strlen($foopoo)>2){$image= "yes";}
```